# $A = B+ C$ then $(B^{-1} - A^{-1})$ and $(C^{-1} - A^{-1})$ are positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ invertible and symmetric square real matrices of dimension $n$.

I want to show that if $A = B+ C$ then $(B^{-1} - A^{-1})$ and $(C^{-1} - A^{-1})$ are positive semidefinite.

For a bit of context, I came across this result when going over some material discussing efficiency of maximum likelihood estimators.

Comment: I don't think this holds without further assumptions. Consider the 1x1 matrices $B=1$ and $C=-0.5$. Then $B^{-1} - A^{-1} = 1^{-1} - (1 - 0.5)^{-1} = 1 - (0.5)^{-1} = 1 - 2 = -1$

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=-2I$, $B=C=-I$. Then $A=B+C$ but $B^{-1}-A^{-1}=-\frac{1}{2}I$ which is negative definite.

If $A, B, C$ were positive semidefinite then I think the claim is true by the following hint:

Hint: $$B(B^{-1}-A^{-1})A=A-B=C\implies T:=B^{-1}-A^{-1}=B^{-1}CA^{-1}.$$